# Read text file content from the project directory and pass parameter to its text

Tags: c#, string

I'm reading text file from the project directory.

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), 
 @"Template\MailContent.txt");

string FileText = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
```

Text file content (with multiple dynamic parameters) will be like in **FileText** variable.

`Hey {UserName}, Congratulations ! you have {Result} this exam.`

and I have data of `UserName` and `Result` will be dynamic. Like,

```
string UserName = "Brijesh";
string Result = "Passed";
```

so, the result should be,

```
string FinalText = Hey Brijesh, Congratulations ! you have Passed this exam.
```

Comment: Use `.Replace()`

Comment: @Loocid yes, I know that. but I have very large number of parameters. In questen I given two just for example.

Comment: Please use (lower)CamelCase for naming your variables, i.e. `finalText`, `username` or `fileText`. Can you drill down your problem to explain it more clearly? I i.e. don't understand wat you mean by "dynamic".

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of the file? At least a relevant chunk with context (several lines)?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), @"Template\MailContent.txt");
string FileText = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
string UserName = "Brijesh";
string Result = "Passed";

 var replacements = new ListDictionary{ {"{UserName}", UserName }, {"{Result}", Result }}

foreach (DictionaryEntry replacement in replacements)
    {
        FileText = FileText.Replace($"{replacement.Key}", $"{replacement.Value}");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's *organize* all substitutions into a collection, say, `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
Dictionary<string, object> replace = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
  {"UserName", "Brijesh"},
  {"Result", "Passed"},
  {"Score", 85},
  {"Grade", "B+"},
  //TODO: Add more parameters here 
};
```

Then I suggest using *regular expressions* in order to match and replace `{Word}` pattern by its value:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string FileText = 
  "Hey {UserName}, Congratulations ! you have {Result} this exam. Your score is {Score}.";

string result = Regex.Replace(FileText, 
   "{[A-Za-z]+}", 
    match => replace.TryGetValue(match.Value.Trim('{', '}'), out var value) 
      ?  value?.ToString()
      : "{???}");           // when we don't have a value

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Hey Brijesh, Congratulations ! you have Passed this exam. Your score is 85.
```